# How to go about freeing an HTML5 video from memory?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a page that uses a lot of videos, I would like to clear the videos from memory when they are paused, but I am unsure how to do it.  I tried using:

```
 function pausevideo1(){
     var video = document.getElementById("video1");
     video.pause();
     video.src =""
 }
```

but this clears the video from the page entirely so it cannot be played again.  Is it possible to clear a video when its paused and reload it again when it is activated?

Comment: What is the point of doing that?

Comment: You can't do anything with browser memory from your script. Browser handles it's own garbage collection

Comment: I think that's in the browser domain,, sort of it's best at it,, don't think that developers should mess with that

Comment: but also if you have bunch of videos on the page, you cound and maybe SHOULD be able to control that only 1 video is played at one time,, and not bunch of them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you clear the `src` of the video, save the `src` in the element's [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), and retrieve it when the user clicks play:

```
function pausevideo1(){

     var video = document.getElementById("video1");

     video.pause();

     video.dataset.vidSrc = video.src; // save src

     video.src ="";
}

function loadVideo(id) {

    var video = document.getElementById(id);

    video.src = video.dataset.vidSrc; // retrieve src
}
```

**Note:** [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) is compatible in IE > 10. If you need a solution that is compatible with old browsers, then you can use a similar solution, but use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` to save the `src` into the element.